# Parsing command line output delimited by underscore

Tags: unix, shell-script, parsing

I've got some command which output looks like that:

> some_command
>   Current view: username_token1_token2_token3_4_token4_2

How could I parse the "token3_4_token4_2" part out of the string?

Comment: What do you mean with "parse out of the string"? Do you want to remove the `token3_4_token4_2` part or do you want to extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in Perl:

```
perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+_){3}//; print $_;'
```

For example:

```
% echo "username_token1_token2_token3_4_token4_2" | perl -ne '$_ =~ s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+_){3}//; print $_;'
token3_4_token4_2
```

Works as follows:

Initially the string `"username_token1_token2_token3_4_token4_2"` is put into the `$_` variable.

#### search and replace

```
s/....//
```

#### Matches a string_ (i.e. part of the .... above)

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+_)
```

#### Matches 3 of them

```
{3}
```

#### replaces  them with nothing (i.e. deletes)

```
//
```

#### print what's left of $_

```
print $_
```

Answer (score 1):

some solutions:

```
awk -F_ '{ print $5"_"$6"_"$7"_"$8 }'
```

.

```
awk '{ print gensub("^.*_([^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)$", "\\1", "g") }'
```

.

```
awk '{ if (match($0, "_([^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)$", a)) print a[1] }'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/^[^:]*:[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*_//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using bash:

```
alias some_command='echo "some_command Current view: username_token1_token2_token3_4_token4_2"'

read a b c < <(some_command)
token=$(IFS=_; set -- $c; shift 3; echo "$*")
echo $token
```

prints

```
token3_4_token4_2
```

I used a process substitution to redirect the output of the command into the read statement. If I were to have used a pipe, then the read would have occurred in a subshell and the $c variable would not have existed in the parent shell.